# Add logrotate config file to aks node

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I want to add logrotate config file for pods and containers on aks node which is a linux machine. I was able to achieve it by login to the node in azure and manually adding them at */etc/logrotate.d* path. But my code has cases where I may have to deploy again which removes those changes. How can I make it persist or add those config files such that they are created on aks node when deployed again?

FYI: I use arm templates for deployment.

Answer (score 1):

with AKS you shouldn't need to setup Log Rotate on the nodes itself to manage log rotation for container.

This is the responsibility of Docker and AKS properly configures the rotation of such logs.

```
xinfra@aks-linux-vmss000000:~$ cat /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
  "live-restore": true,
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts":  {
     "max-size": "50m",
     "max-file": "5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You mentioned above that AKS configures the rotation of logs. So if I want to change the config for suppose max-size, max-file or max-age where should I look for.

Comment: please have a look at this question, I have provided a workaround https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61224490/change-docker-daemon-configuration-on-aks-node/61232582#61232582

Comment: Thanks that was what I'm looking for. And also I am also looking to configure log rotation based on age rather size. In docker daemon configuration, there is no such attribute that relates to age of the log.