# Change docker daemon configuration on AKS node?

Tags: azure-container-service

I would like to change the docker daemon configuration regarding the size and time at which log rotation can happen. Is there any arm template config or az cli command where I can change this configuration on AKS node.

Answer (score 1):

Right now both AKS and AKS-Engine don't allow for the ContainerRuntime configuration to be provided/overwritten.

there is a PR on the AKS-Engine that will allow exposing the dataDir configuration of the containerRuntime.

https://github.com/Azure/aks-engine/pull/3072

It. might be worth while to shine in with your request to see if this is something they could also expose.

Also, while not supported, you could leverage https://github.com/juan-lee/knode to change the node configuration. It supposed docker daemon settings.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible today in a supported way. AKS is a managed service and tends to prefer managing low level details like this on behalf of the customer. Especially considering the shift away from docker to containerd, exposing this configuration directly to users would be difficult to manage as things change in the underlying implementation. So I find it unlikely AKS would expose these settings directly.

If you're really interested in node configuration, you can use a daemonset or ssh to nodes and configure them as you desire. But this will take you out of support. Proceed with caution!

Check this out for an example: https://github.com/juan-lee/knode

(btw, I'm the author of the AKS-Engine PR djsly linked and I work on this topic for AKS. That said, opinions on future developments are my own.)